# How to monitor if a Groupview in an expandableListView has been showing for 2 seconds

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am using an expandableListView, that has 2 types of group views, and off course children views. My question is as written in the title, How to know if a  GroupView is showing now on the screen and it has been showing for 2 seconds or more

Comment: What solution have you tried? I would try a Runnable.

Comment: I thought of that, I can set a Runnable to start as the view is on screen, but that Runnable would execute even if the view went out of screen

Comment: Then the runnalbe should check periodicly, if the view is still on screen.